# WinForms: adding a control with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, controls, desktop

I'm new to c#, and I do know how to dynamically add controls, but I don't know how to set that control as `this.[control_name]`. Note that here, `this` is the `Form`.

This can be done statically with `private System.Windows.Forms.[Control_type] [control-name];`, but how would i do this from a method so that I can later declare `this.[control-name] = [variable]`?

Note here, `variable` would be something like `new TextBox()`;

Comment: I am doing this because I need to be able to reference to the control from another scope from the one in which the control was created. So I would use `this.[control-name]` as this would be universal in all scopes.

Comment: You can’t do this because the code wouldn’t compile

Comment: You could though have a dictionary of controls with the name as the key

Comment: @stuartd then I would use `Form.Controls.Find([dict],true)[0]`, I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var txt = new TextBox();  //txt is the variable you are looking for
Form1.Controls.Add(txt); //added it to the form
```

Now you can access it by `txt`:

```
txt.Location = new Point(0,0);
txt.Visible = true;
```

If you create the control inside a method (as you mentioned in the comments), you can return and use it like below:

```
public TextBox AddTextBox()
{
    var txt = new TextBox();  
    Form1.Controls.Add(txt); 
    return txt;
}

var newTxt = AddTextBox();
newTxt.Location = new Point(0,0);
newTxt.Visible = true;
```

Comment: But if I did the first part of the code inside a method, and then the second outside of that method, there would be a reference error. How would I be able to reference to this textbox outside of the method it is created in? Thanks .

Comment: Declare the variable in the scope you wish to access it from, e.g. outside of the function in your form class.

Comment: Ah, yes that works! Thank you. I had to use a dict as well, to add a number on the end of each control's name so each name was unique.